# CordovaWebView: Black screen when change div from display:none to display:block or use css3 translate

Tags: android, android-webview, cordovawebview

When I add a class to make appear a div (display:block) , suddenly view change to black screen. I touch the screen, elements in view still fire event.

How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are using the most recent API (You can probably adjust this in eclipses android sdk manager).

If you still have any issues, make sure you have hardware acceleration on. You can adjust this in the manifest file:

```
<application
    ...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    ...
>
```

If you still have an issue, try applying a css3 translate to something like your global body on app load. That will help to narrow down the issue. Otherwise, without some more code/information it's going to be hard to answer.

Let me know if I can help with anything else, but for what it's worth I haven't had this issue at all using the most recent android API and cordova 4.0.